# Remove statically added controls at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

**The Scenario:** I have an asp.net website where I show a div popup on page load for taking a few user details. When a user inputs the details, or closes the popup, I set up a flag cookie so that the popup is not displayed again for the user. The div is in the MasterPage so that it is displayed no matter on which page a user lands first time. The div contains an UpdatePanel which has all the controls required for taking the details. This whole functionality is working fine.

**The Problem:** Now this div popup is not showing(by setting display:none) on subsequent postbacks(which I want), but the html markup is still loading with the page unnecessarily adding to the page size. What I would idealy want to do is: Check if flag cookie is set. If no, show the popup, else remove the popup's markup from the page.

Now since the div is not a server control, I cannot possibly remove it and the all the controls inside it. So, I thought of removing the UpdatePanel from the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["flag"] != null)
        {
            if (Page.Controls.Contains(updpnl_contact))
            {
                Page.Controls.Remove(updpnl_contact);
                updpnl_contact.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

But I guess this tends to work with dynamically added controls only, and since the control is added at Design Time, it is not being removed.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not at all the usual workflow. I tend to think that it will not work as it would mess up control tree, maybe even corrupt the viewstate and so on.

As a possible solution, you can put it's visibility to hidden in the code behind. This, in the contrary to the usual 'gut feeling', doesn't work like the css propery 'display:none' for example - instead the control will not even be rendered into the page when it's not visible. This may be the workaround for you.

Happy coding.

Comment: well, I did try using `Visible=false;` but that doesn't prevent the the UpdatePanel from being rendered.

Comment: As I am a beginner in programming, I'd like to know what according to you should be the Ideal workflow.

Comment: Simply wrap the updatepanel and everything else you want to hide into an <asp:Panel></Panel> and set the visibility to false for that Panel on server side. This way you'll get the best of both worlds. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I have just finished tried what you suggested but still the markup is being shown.

Comment: Sorry my bad. It works, it was just that I had put the test condition `if (Page.Controls.Contains(pnl_contact))` before setting the visibility as false, and this condition was somehow not giving true. But anyways, it works now, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you add a `runat="server"` attribute to your `<div>` element, it *will* be available in the code-behind. You'll need an `id` on it as well. Then you can just toggle the `Visible` property. If this property is `false`, the control won't be rendered to the client (i.e. no HTML markup).

Comment: +1 - and to clarify, setting visible to 'false' means it won't be output in the HTML.

Comment: but I don't want the div to run at server, as doing so will cause a full postback when the user submits the details. And yes I also tried using `updpnl_contact.Visible=false;` but even that didn't stop the updatepanel from being rendered.

Comment: @Anchit - I'm not sure what you mean, as I understand it your div is in an UpdatePanel which is presumably doing an Ajax Postback when a button is clicked or something. Adding `runat="server"` to the div will not affect this.

Comment: actually it's the other way round, the UpdatePanel is inside the div.

Comment: @Anchit- ok, well you should just be able to set the `Visible` property of this if you've got the `runat="server"` attribute. This won't have any affect on the behaviour of the UpdatePanel.

Comment: OK, so I get it, it means only the UpdatePanel's visibility is the issue here.

Comment: @Skorpioh - that's basically the same as adding the `runat="server"` attribute to the div.

Comment: @Graham - So this will also cause a full postback?

Comment: @Anchit - the only thing that controls whether you do a full or an ajax postback is the UpdatePanel. If you don't have any `PostBackTrigger` elements in your UpdatePanel, it won't do a full postback. Any controls containing your UpdatePanel will *not* affect this.

Comment: OK, got it now. I have finally wrapped the UpdatePanel inside another panel whose visibility I am setting to false on server side according to the cookie, I have used the panel instead of a div as I also had to set a default submit button for the UpdatePanel. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient approach would be to create the panel as a UserControl and load it dynamically in codebehind when it's needed, then add it to your page. E.g, in code:

```
MyPopupControl popup = (MyPopupControl)Page.LoadControl("/path/to/usercontrol.ascx");
PopupPanel.Controls.Add(popup);
```

Where PopupPanel is an empty `<asp:Panel>`. Then, not even the markup will need to be loaded/processed except when its needed.

There is no reason that all the code you use to display and process this panel couldn't also be in the usercontrol, isolating it from the master page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you build the panel dynamically, based on the cookie setting?

Comment: Possible, but not viable, since there are many controls in it plus the validations and everything.

Comment: Can you change it to be a custom control and add that dyanimcally as needed?